# How to set repository-config in package.json from OpenAPI Maven Plugin?

Tags: maven, openapi-generator

When generating the TypeScript client, the `repository` field in the resulting `package.json` looks like this:

```json
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/GIT_USER_ID/GIT_REPO_ID.git"
  },
```

and I am unable to change these values. Or at least I can't find the correct properties in order to change this.

I'm used to create a `.npmrc` file in order to publish these clients but I suspect that it is this `url` from the `package.json` file which is getting picked up, instead of what is configured in the `.npmrc` file.

So, how should the `<configOptions>` look like in my `pom.xml`?

```xml
<configOptions>
  <!-- This has no effect: -->
  <gitUserId>user-id</gitUserId>
  <gitRepoId>repo-id</gitRepoId>
</configOptions>
```

Comment: If I correctly remember the java generator does not have an kind of configuration like that? What tell the docs about that?

Comment: @khmarbaise There I can see that properties for `gitUserId` and `Repo` are exposed ([see docs](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md)) - I think I remember now that this not working was the reason why I had to setup the OpenAPI generator and everything manually in my GitHub actions..

Answer (score 0):

The `configOptions` are for generator specific options.

From [the documentation](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator-maven-plugin/README.md#general-configuration-parameters) for the maven plugin, the `configOptions` are:

> a map of generator-specific parameters. To show a full list of generator-specified parameters (options), please use configHelp

The `gitUserId` and `gitRepoId` options are specific to the maven plugin, and should be defined directly.  Instead of defining them as `configOptions`, try moving them to the top-level configuration settings, like this:

```xml
<configuration>
  <inputSpec>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/api.yaml</inputSpec>
  <generatorName>typescript-axios</generatorName>
  <gitUserId>user-id</gitUserId>
  <gitRepoId>repo-id</gitRepoId>
</configuration>
```